# sql server catalog view to help generate stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

We can use `sql-server's` catalog views to generate/re-create table(s) easily. I can run queries like

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES -- Get all the table names
```

find there column like this..

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'Publishers' -- Get the cols for publisher table
```

I can query like this in `sys.objects` and/or in `sys.foreign_keys` to get the complete information regarding a table, all the columns, if they are nullable or not and everything else (`primary key`, `check constraints` etc.), and given that information I can recreate that table in easily, in its entirety (including constraints and everything). It may sound like a bad idea, and there maybe other ways to do this, but that not the question that is it a good practice or not. What I wanna know is, is there a catalog that contains entire information about `stored procedure(s)`?

Say I have a proc like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_Author]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Flag INT = 1,
    @AuthorName NVARCHAR(50) = '',
    @AuthorId int = 0,
    @Address NVARCHAR(50) = ''
AS
BEGIN

    IF (@Flag = 1)
    -- INSERTS INTO TABLE DATA --
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Authors VALUES (@AuthorName, @Address);

        END

    ELSE IF (@Flag = 2)
        -- DELETES THE AUTHOR --
        BEGIN
            DELETE FROM Authors
            Where AuthorID = @AuthorId
        END

    END
```

Is there any way for me to query the `system catalog` and know the structure of my `Proc_Author` so that I could reconstruct it? I know I can query `sys.procedures`, but it only shows trivial details,  I also ran

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS
select * from sys.parameters
```

though they do give me information about the params my procs are using, its not enough if one wants to construct `proc` from information. So, I am missing something? Could all the information required to construct be obtained from `catalog views`, if yes? Then which one(s)? If not, then after a `stored proc` is complied where are the statement (`select`, `insert` or whatever) are actually stored in disk? When I open my `SSMS` and right click and select `Modify` at a procedure, it opens up the `proc` in a new query window, so for it it open up, it must be looking from somewhere in `disk/catalog views` to know what is the structure of this `proc`? How can I obtain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking in here:

```
select * from sys.all_sql_modules
```

You can also get the script for a stored procedure like this:

```
select object_definition(object_id('[dbo].[proc_Author]'))
```

When using these, check your options for returning text in Management Studio:

> Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> SQL Server -> Results to Text ->
>   Maximum number of characters displayed in each column

There is a limit to the amount of text that will be returned. You might need to BCP it out to a file to view the whole thing.